# Compare subparts of data series in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (from a csv file) that has different measurements for several features of some running program.

```
> bench
   features  input_sizes  arithmetic.mean
1        ui     70000000         3714.195
2        un      1500000           83.695
3        cn      1500000         6056.261
4        ui      2000000          144.052
5        ci      2000000         1606.531
6  …
```

I am able to plot these data and compare the features to each other (`arithmetic.mean` dependent on `input_sizes` grouped by `features`).

However, I am interested in the difference between certain feature series, the `u*` series vs. the `c*` series.

For this example, and the data points at hand: 
`cn - un` at 1500000 would be 5972.566, or 98.6% and 
`ci - ui` at 2000000 would be 1462.479, or 91%

How can I easily derive this data?

I also plan to plot the absolute difference as bar chart relative to a centered 0 and the percentage as line chart, both in the same diagram, is this easily possible with `ggplot2`?

Comment: Do you really have a `data.table` or merely a `data.frame`?

Comment: It is a `data.frame`, read using `read.table`

Comment: Do you have many c*-u* for each input_sizes?

Comment: not that many, I have 3 c* and matching 3 u*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="   features  input_sizes  arithmetic.mean
1        ui     70000000         3714.195
2        un      1500000           83.695
3        cn      1500000         6056.261
4        ui      2000000          144.052
5        ci      2000000         1606.531", header=TRUE)

#split the feature id
DF$feat1 <- substr(DF$features,1,1)
DF$feat2 <- substr(DF$features,2,2)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- dcast(DF, input_sizes+feat2~feat1, value.var="arithmetic.mean")
DF1$diff <- DF1$c-DF1$u

#   input_sizes feat2        c        u     diff
# 1     1500000     n 6056.261   83.695 5972.566
# 2     2000000     i 1606.531  144.052 1462.479
# 3    70000000     i       NA 3714.195       NA
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I right that `input_size` then cannot occur more than there are features classes?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Nevermind, I had made a selection error previously, resulting in more than one input size (eg 1500000) per feature (eg u or c), which caused   `dcast` to not work. but now I got it.